# How to constantly receive requests from socket python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, user-interface, server, client

I'm learning about sockets in python and as practice I made a python gui app with a text box, two entry boxes and a button. It works like a chat app, I can run many modules at once, and in each, when a user enters text and click send, it shows the message entered, on the text box of the user's module and all other modules open. I've gotten most of it working but the issue is that it only updates the text box when the send button is pressed but I want to update constantly so as soon as a new message is sent, it shows it on the screen.

Here's my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):
        ... #code that creates widgets shortended for readability
        #text box widget named self.txt

        self.send_btn["command"] = self.send_msg //this handles sending messages to the server when the button is pressed

        ... #code that creates widgets shortended for readability

    def send_msg(self):
        s = socket.socket()
        host = socket.gethostname()
        port = 9999


        address = (host, port)
        msg=self.name_bar.get() + ": " +self.input_bar.get()
        #name bar is another widget so I can enter an identity for each module
        #input bar is the entry box where text is entered in
        self.input_bar.delete(0, len(msg))

        s.connect(address)
        s.send(msg.encode())

        #Wrote this code that updates textbox when button pushed
        #self.txt.insert(tk.END, s.recv(1024)) 
        #self.txt.insert(tk.END, "\n")

    #Method I created to call constantly to update textbox
    def rcv_msg(self):
        s = socket.socket()
        host = socket.gethostname()
        port = 9999

        address = (host, port)

        s.connect(address)

        if s.recv(1024).decode() != "":
            #self.txt.insert(tk.END, s.recv(1024)) 
            #self.txt.insert(tk.END, "\n")
```

Also I been doing Java lately so I apologise if my terminology is mixed up.
I've already made the method to update the text box, I just don't know how to call it, I tried a while loop but it just stops the app from running. Also, the server is really simple and just sends the message from the client above to all the all modules of the client open. I din't know if the code was necessary, I was told previously to try to keep questions short but if it's needed please tell me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could have something listening for new information. A separate thread that doesn't interfere with the GUI. (Pseudo code ahead!)

```
import socket
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time

class ListenThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, app, lock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._app = app
        self._lock = lock
        self._terminating = False

    def destroy(self):
        self._terminating = True

    def run(self):
        s = socket.socket()
        host = socket.gethostname()
        port = 9999
        address = (host, port)

        while True:

            if self._terminating:
                break;

            if s.recv(1024).decode() != "":
                self._lock.acquire()
                self._app.post_new_data(s.recv(1024))
                self._lock.release()
            time.sleep(0.1)

class App(object):

    # ...

    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._listener = ListenThread(self, self._lock)
        self._listener.start()

    def post_new_data(self, data):

        # Post information to the GUI

    def all_data(self):
        self._lock.acquire()
        # ...
        self._lock.release()

    def destroy(self):
        self._listener.destroy()


# ... Tk mainloop ...
```

### Breakdown

---

```
class ListenThread(Thread):
```

This is the item that will listen for new data coming from other connections and post them to the GUI via `self._app.post_new_data(...)` call in the `run(self)` operation.

```
    def run(self):
        s = socket.socket()
```

When we first start the execution on a thread (via `start()`) we create our socket and get a connection going. This way, all incoming transmissions will route through this in order to keep our GUI free for things it likes to do (paint the interface, take on user input, etc.)

The `while` loop on the `ListenThread.run` will keep looking for new data until we've killed the thread. As soon as it receives data, it will push that information to our `App`. In the `post_new_data` function, you can add our new data onto the GUI, store it, whatever you would like.

```
    def post_new_data(self, data):
        self.txt.insert(tk.END, data)
        self.txt.insert(tk.END, "\n")
```

Comment: in your all_data method, what's meant to be in place of the ellipses?

Comment: Also your `_init_` method in the `App` class, would I add it's contents to the `_init_` method of my `Application` class? and if so, where exactly

Comment: also, I tried this but now the app doesn't send messages to the server when the send button is pressed, and the module doesn't close even after the window is closed anymore

Comment: Also should listener.start be listener.run()?

Comment: That's quite a few questions. The `all_data` method can return whatever you would like. The idea being you should try to acquire the lock whenever interacting with data that the both the app and the thread will need. Yes `start()` is correct. That will push the execution to a thread. As for the "doesn't close issue" you have to make sure you `destroy()` the application. You can also look into `atexit` if you don't want to explicitly make that call. Just some method of terminating the thread before you exit.